# Cannot Connect to SQL Named Instance using TCP/IP and 127.0.0.1 Loopback IP Address

Tags: sql-server, tcp

Evening all,

We have been tasked to connect to our named server instance using SQLCMD below:

**- Use SQLCMD to test connecting to the (named instance) TCP/IP listener
   on TCP port 1433. Use the 127.0.0.1 loopback address to simulate the
   network.**

I have tried just about every method of connecting I can think of including the following basic scripts:

1. sqlcmd -S tcp:MyComputerName,1433
2. sqlcmd -S tcp:127.0.0.1,1433
3. sqlcmd.exe -S tcp:MyComputerName,1433 -Q "select getdate()"

This is the error I continually get:

- Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
- Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0: A network-related or instance-specific error has occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I went through all the troubleshooting methods to ensure my Firewall accepts port 1433. I ensured Remote Connections could be accepted using the SQL Server Management Tool. TCP/IP protocol is enabled under all three areas of the Network Configuration Tool. The ports are 1433 in each protocol.

I am utterly confused.

I will say that there is one script I do get a positive connection via tcp and that is the following:

- sqlcmd -S tcp:MyComputerName\SQLSERVERNAME

I end up with 1> to let me know the connection was good.

After researching this for quite some time I have turned to posting as I have been unable to troubleshoot a solution.

Thoughts?

*edit* 
Just got this error for the first time:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0: TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: What happens when you try `ping localhost`?  Or `telnet localhost 1433`?

Comment: If I ping 1433 I get Transmit Failed. 100% loss. Telnet doesn't work as I get "not recognized as an internal or external command...". When I ping Localhost I get 0% packet loss with a time<1ms.

Comment: I guess your SQL Server is not configured to accept TCP/IP connections. Check your SQL Server Manager to find out.

Comment: Sheesh. I figured it out. I never manually restarted the SQL Server within the Server Manager after I made the changes to the TCP/IP to the default port for All Ports to 1433. Once I forced the restart, the connection was established for all script methods of connecting. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check whether the "SQLSERVERAGENT" service is running.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem too, right after a bran  new installation of *SQL-Server 2008r2 Developer* on a Windows 10.

As Tim3890 pointed out, The issue was just that TCP/IP was not enable for the local SQL server.

see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62165/i-cant-connect-to-my-servers-sql-database-via-an-ip-address